# Make a broken gear bike a fixie

Tags: gears, fixed-gear

Hi sadly my gear is broken. Now my idea was to remove the gear and shorten the bicycle chain to make the bike a fixie. It's a bike with 7 gears at the back wheel and no gear at the front.

What do you think is this possible? Which gear should I select for a fixie. I guess the feeling without the gear is different than without the thing to move the gear.

Comment: This isn't easily done.  You'd probably need a "chain tensioner".

Comment: A 'fixie' is not just a single speed bike.  It means a bike where the chain and wheel are locked together so you cannot "coast" and if you pedal backward the bike would actually move backward.  Are you asking about an actual fixie (which isn't really practical to convert from a frame intended for derailleur gears) or just what to do to make it rideable as a single-speed?

Comment: Depending on what exactly is broken (or better said, what isn't), you may be able to use the same derailleur as a tensioner by using the limit screws to keep it in a fixed position so you use a single cog. Other changes may not be strictly necessary (even if aesthetics suffer a bit), so this is the least money needed route.

Comment: What, precisely, is broken?

Comment: 7 speed bits are cheap enough its possibly going to cost less to fix the broken bit than make the bike single speed.

Comment: Thanks to all here. Im interested in making it an rideable single-speed. Expected to need a chain tensioner. The metal peace which holds the gear is broken. just cracked after a weird noise

Comment: My suggestion would be to start by reading through https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help and https://www.sheldonbrown.com/ so that you'd at least know the terminology. You have much better chance to succeed when you know the difference between single speed and fixed gear and what's that "metal peace" called.